# Android start another application without rendering in current one

Tags: android

I would like to ask how to start another application without rendering in current one in android.

The problem is, in application A, if I do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_MAIN", Uri.parse(url));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.foo", "com.foo.bar.activity"));
```

It will render activity from B in application A rather than switching to B.

Comment: What do you mean by another application? Is it another activity? or A whole new android application?

Answer (score 0):

this way create an intent to view a map, verify that an app exists to handle the intent, then start it:

// Build the intent

```
Uri appuri = 
Uri.parse("your.uri.to.app");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, appuri);
```

// Verify it resolves

```
 PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
 List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, 0);
 boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

// Start an activity if it's safe

```
 if (isIntentSafe) {
   startActivity(mapIntent);
 }
```

//to choose an app from existing apps create an Intent using createChooser() and pass it to startActivity(). For example:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   ...
```

// Always use string resources for UI text. says something like "Share this photo with"

```
 String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
```

// Create intent to show chooser

```
  Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
```

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity

```
 if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
  startActivity(chooser);
  }
```

hope this will help you